# Three.js - Strange lines on custom mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, rendering, mesh

I'm trying to make a custom mesh in order to have a lot of customizable planes in the scene.

Here is some code:

```
geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

geometry.addAttribute( 'position',  new THREE.BufferAttribute( vertexPositions, 3 ).setDynamic( true ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'color',     new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ).setDynamic( true ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'opacity',   new THREE.BufferAttribute( opacity, 1 ).setDynamic( true ) );

// Initialize material
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, transparent: true, vertexShader: vertexShader, fragmentShader: fragmentShader } );

// Create something like a Wireframe of the planes
var Pgeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
Pgeometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( ApointsPositions ), 3 ).setDynamic( true ) );
var points = new THREE.LineSegments( Pgeometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color: 0x353535 } ) );
scene.add( points );

// Create planes and add to scene
planeMeshes = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
planeMeshes.setDrawMode( THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode );
scene.add( planeMeshes );
```

My custom material is working fine and let me to use opacity on every vertex. Every plane is created and everything works fine.

The problem is that, when I render the scene, there are some strange lines on every planes row, here's a full working Codepen: [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/ThoughtsRiff/pen/WapjwX?editors=0010)

Do you see those diagonal lines there? Are you able to tell me what's happening? I didn't find their origin.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I do see a straight grid, and additional gray diagonals created by `planeMeshes`. What's the desired behavior?

Comment: I don't want those long diagonals. Are you sure they are from planeMeshes?
EDIT: planeMeshes are supposed to be just squared planes. They are a lot of triangle pairs.

Comment: When I comment out `scene.add( planeMeshes );`, they go away.

Comment: Oh, yes, I knew that :D I meant, in the post I ask why it's doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing diagonals is because you're using [`THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/constants/DrawModes), so the rightmost triangles share vertices with the leftmost triangles of the next row. You're seeing a really stretched out triangle cut across.

To solve this, get rid of the line where you're assigning `TriangleStripDrawMode`, which will go back to the default of three vertices per triangle (no sharing of vertices).

**Problem 2:**

The first triangle on each iteration is being drawn in a clockwise order, but the second triangle on each iteration is being drawn in a counter-clockwise order, so you will not see the second one unless you change the vertex order to be clockwise.

Here's how you have it in your Codepen:

```
// Second tri is drawn counter-clockwise
AvertexPositions.push( x,        y + 60, 0 ); //
AvertexPositions.push( x + 80,   y + 60, 0 ); // Second triangle of a plane
AvertexPositions.push( x + 80,   y,      0 );
```

This is how it should be:

```
// Now, it is clockwise, matching first tri
AvertexPositions.push( x,        y + 60, 0 ); //
AvertexPositions.push( x + 80,   y,      0 ); //
AvertexPositions.push( x + 80,   y + 60, 0 ); // Second triangle of a plane
```

It is important to draw all your triangles in the same winding order. Otherwise, some will be facing forward, and some will be facing backward. You can choose which side gets rendered, or render both sides with [`Materials.Side`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/constants/Materials)

Comment: Nice reply @Marquizzo!! Thank you! It "solved" the problem.

About THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode:  I changed the loop. I draw 1 row from left to right and then 1 row from right to left, so the common vertex is on the same side!

About clockwise triangles: was that triangle already clockwise?? It was just starting from a different corner, so it was like this:

. _____ .
            |
            |
            .

Anyway I updated the codepen. Why are they showing diagonals inside? [link](https://codepen.io/ThoughtsRiff/pen/WapjwX?editors=0010)

Thank for your time!

Comment: You need to read the link I gave you. It explains how `TriangleStripDrawMode` works: (v0, v1, v2), (v2, v1, v3), (v2, v3, v4). Your loop is still creating the vertices as if you were using `TrianglesDrawMode`. You should take out a piece of paper, and draw your loop one vertex at a time, you'll see why.

Comment: Hey! I've been busy. I figured it out! https://codepen.io/ThoughtsRiff/pen/WapjwX?editors=0010 Thank you man

Comment: Nice! There you go!